# Qt + QTextEdit content into QDomDocument

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I'm having `QTextEdit` widget with large (XML) content in it, so I take the content using:

```
document = textEdit->document();
```

How do I set it into a `QDomDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
QDomDocument *xmlDocument = new QDomDocument();
QString error;
int errorLine = 0;
int errorColumn = 0;
bool docStatus = xmlDocument->setContent(textEdit->toPlainText()->toAscii(),&error,&errorLine,&errorColumn);
```

It isn't tested. But hope it will work.. Check it out..

Edit: 
Alternatively give

```
bool docStatus = xmlDocument->setContent(textEdit->toPlainText(),&error,&errorLine,&errorColumn);
```

This is a better one when compared to the previous.

Comment: oops... its a bit of misunderstanding.. try change textEdit->toPlainText()->toAscii(); I edit my answer too..

Comment: I think you dont have to convert to Byte array at all i.e toAscii().. Try giving xmlDocument->setContent(textEdit->toPlainText(),&error,&errorLine,&errorColumn);.. Sorry I couldn't test by myself.. Check and let know..

Comment: toAscii() returns QByteArray
what results in "no match for call to '(QByteArray) ()'"

Comment: Why toAscii() ? setContent takes a QString, let Qt do the content encoding conversion.

Comment: @ kaycee,the prototype bool setContent  ( const QByteArray & buffer, QString * errorMsg = 0, int * errorLine = 0, int * errorColumn = 0 ) is available. hence it should work. Instead try giving without toAscii from my answer, as i said in my previous comment. It is the better one. Both will work though.