# QTextEdit content into QDomDocument

Tags: qt, qtextedit

i'm having QTextEdit widget with large content in it (content is XML).
i want to take the content and set it into a QDomDocument, so i take the content using

```
document = textEdit->document();
```

but i dont know how to take it from here into a QDomDocument...
what's the best way to do it ?

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938424/qt-qtextedit-content-into-qdomdocument.. Isn't it??

Answer (score 1):

Is there any problem with QTextEdit::toPlainText and QDomDocument::setContent?